# Hierarchical model with a different set of covariates by group

Tags: multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian

I'd appreciate any good reference material on specifying a hierarchical model with a different set of covariates by group. Textbooks usually reference varying intercepts and slopes, but in my real world example I'd like to specify a different set covariates by group. Technically, this should be like a varying slope model with a pre-defined set of coefficients set to zero, depending on the group/level.

Comment: Can you please elaborate with more details? Are you meaning that some covariates are 0 for certain groups only?

Comment: Why don’t you set a prior for those coefficients which is zero for the specific groups?

Comment: Yes, correct. I want to specify a different set of covariates for each group. I could specify coefficients with zero mean prior for specific groups, as you suggest, but I also need to ensure the posterior is zero.

Comment: If the prior is zero the posterior is zero since it’s proportional to the product of prior and likelihood.

Comment: so assume a normal prior with mean zero. At what value do I specify the variance?

Comment: No your prior will be zero for the fixed groups that are expected to not have the relationship with the covariate. The other groups will be sampled from the same continuous distribution with parameters determined from the data (using the hyperpriors) as you usually do for hierarchical models.

Comment: BTW, even though it may be theoretically done (by setting a prior to zero for a group), I don't see why you want to include a covariate that is not defined for a group of observations. Also, please remember that linear models are designed to capture a relationship between the predictors and the independent variable. If a predictor is not defined for a group of observations you cannot even use a hierarchical model, because the cluster level coefficients cannot be sampled from the same distribution. In that case, it may be better running a separate linear model for each group.